# Uninstall pip dependency with a hyphen at the start of it's name

Tags: command-line, package-management, pip

I accidentally globally installed a package called `-igalixir` with pip3. When I try to uninstall it with `pip3 uninstall -igalixir` it interprets `-igalixir` as a command line option. I have tried surrounding it with quotes which also doesn't work.

The output of `pip3 list` and `pip3 freeze` are as follows:

```
$ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
-igalixir  1.0.19
click      6.7
pip        19.0.3
proxy.py   0.3
Pygments   2.2.0
requests   2.13.0
rollbar    0.13.18
setuptools 40.8.0
six        1.12.0
stripe     1.51.0
wheel      0.33.1

$ pip3 freeze
Could not parse requirement: -igalixir
click==6.7
proxy.py==0.3
Pygments==2.2.0
requests==2.13.0
rollbar==0.13.18
six==1.12.0
stripe==1.51.0
```

I'm not even sure how I installed it in the first place if it is an invalid package name. Is there anyway to cleanly purge this from my system. I don't want any random files hanging around my system - so I prefer if it uninstalled properly.

EDIT

I tried to separate the `-igialixir` term with `--`, like so: `pip3 uninstall -- -igalixir`, and although it does not interpret `-igialixar` as a command line option any more, it still doesn't accept it because it is an invalid requirement.

```
$ pip3 uninstall -- -igalixir
Invalid requirement: '-igalixir'
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `pip`'s internal API to call it from a Python program, but it's [not really supported](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). Why not install a dummy package, then uninstall with `-v` and check the paths, then manually repeat the deletion commands with your faulty package?

Comment: I'm having same issue. Any luck with this?

Comment: @rekans I'm afraid not, my solution was to reinstall pip3 IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are interpreted and stripped by the shell, pip doesn't even receive them.

The standard way to deal with such cases in GNU utilities is to use the double dash:

```
sometool -somearg -otherarg -- -these -are -interpreted -as -file -names
```

I guess pip may use this convention too.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately didn't have any luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation. What worked for me was to run the following command to see where the installation resides:

```
pip show -- -pkgname
```

I then went to that folder and simply removed the offending folder (it was listed with a hyphen but the folder name started with a tilde sign, ~pkgname).

That solved the issue in my case.